# Hive not picking up new entries appended to a file?

Tags: hadoop, hive, flume

I have an external hive table [1], pointing to a `somepath` directory in HDFS. Here's the sequence of events I'm concerned with:

1. Some process (Flume in this case) creates a new file `somefile` in the `somepath` and writes one row to that file.
2. I query the table from Hive. The select correctly returns the row written in step 1.
3. Flume appends another row to `somefile`.
4. Now, here's the problem: I query the table again from Hive. The SELECT does not show the row appended in step 3.

Can someone suggest a way to fix this? My theory is that Hive has internally cached the contents of `somefile` and so is not reading the new content from HDFS.

`[1] CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE metrics (timestamp STRING, workflow STRING, result STRING) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( "input.regex" = ".*timestamp\":([0-9]+).*counters\":\\{\"\\.(.*?)\\.(.*?)\".*") LOCATION 'somepath';`

Comment: can you provide some sample data when you have two rows in your file? maybe the issue is how flume is appending the data

Comment: From what I've seen, the file content is not a problem - once the file gets closed by flume, Hive sees the correct content (which it didn't see before, even though file content was the same). I suspect it's because only then the file timestamp is updated, and this triggers a reload in Hive?

Comment: Hive read the files at runtime, I am not aware about any chaching, maybe it is because the files is not closed yet.